# Bounded AR(1) Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, time-series

I am trying to estimate an AR(1) model for a stochastic process Xt that is bounded in some interval (a,b]. Is there a simple transformation I can do on Xt that ensures my AR(1) model does not violate those bounds when I simulate it? Maybe something like a sigmoid function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use a sigmoid function $\sigma:\mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ (and rescale it) so that you can use errors $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ which are $e_n:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ without restricting their distribution, but obtaining a bounded AR(p) 'type' process (in the sense that it depends on the previous $p$ terms). For example the one lag version could be
$$X_n=\sigma(\phi_0+\phi_1X_{n-1}+e_n)$$
However, mind that the distribution of $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ might become quite atypical, which is not always desirable, and its autocorrelation function esoteric. This is the empirical density by using $\sigma(x)=(1+e^{-x})^{-1}$ (which bounds the process in $(0,1)$) and choices $\phi_0=-0.2,\phi_1=-0.9,\sigma_e=0.8$ with Gaussian errors:

[image]

Comment: Thank you this is a very helpful response. Question: How would you approach be different than the following: Suppose I have a time-series, X, I'm trying to fit an AR(1) type process, and empirically it is bounded in (0,1) and I want my model to be as well. What if I transformed Xt with  a logit (inverse of sigmoid) function  Yt = log (Xt/(1-Xt)). And then I estimated an AR1 process  on Yt. Is that different than what you suggest?

Comment: I see what you're referring to. I think the equation would be
$$\sigma^{-1}(X_n)=\phi_0+\phi_1 \sigma^{-1}(X_{n-1})+e_n$$
Which it might be different from the process above (it would be a data transformation)

Comment: Please take a look at [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508).